# What to use instead of list in python for loops - fourier example from java

Tags: java, python, list, loops, fft

I am trying to code a fourier transform by hand in Python, but have less experience in Python than in Java.

I am assuming lists are not the best thing to use in a for loop, and I am also assuming this code is not very pythonic and there might be better syntax for what I am trying to do.

I input a simple test=[10, 10, 10, -10, -10, -10, 10, 10, 10, -10, -10,-10]

I get the error 'list' object attribute 'instert' is read-only.

What data type would be better?

```
import math
pi = math.pi

def dft(x):
    X=[]
    N = len(x)
    re = 0
    im = 0
    for k in range(0,N):
        for n in range(0,N):
            phi = (2*pi*k*n)/N

            re += (x[n]*math.cos(phi))
            im -= (x[n]*math.sin(phi))

    re = re/N
    im = im/N
    h = (re, im)
    X.insert = (k,h) #object with real and imaginary component

    return (X)
```

Comment: Aside from your question, it looks like you might need to indent the lines which calculate 're', 'im, 'h' and  the insert, those are not happening as part of the k loop

Answer (score 3):

A list is fine.

`X.insert = (k,h)` is attempting to assign the tuple (k,h) to the `insert` attribute of `X`. You want to call the `insert` method instead.

```
X.insert(k,h)
```

**Note:** You also need to check your indentation. That statement is not currently inside the loop.

Comment: From my understanding the insert method takes in the index and the element. I had it before as X[k] = (re, im) but python did not like that either.
You are right on the indentation, I need to update X with the k loop.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question directly: you have the right data structure (i.e. a `list`). However, you also have some serious Python/algorithm issues.** Let's start with high level issues and then go down from there...

**First of all, what you have there is a naive DFT, not an FFT**. The question is tagged FFT, although you don't reference the FFT anywhere in the question itself, so maybe you already know this but I thought I'd mention it for others who may not. The FFT runs in `O(N log N)`. What you have runs in `O(N^2)`. Big difference. They both output the same thing as they are both Fourier transforms (although scale factors can make them different in terms of implementation), but one is fast (hence the **F**FT). Using a naive DFT doesn't usually buy you much: we use FFTs because they're computationally efficient. If they weren't, we'd do everything in the time domain and be done with it!

**Secondly your indent/algorithm is not correct.** You need to have:

```
re = 0
im = 0
```

right before each inner loop.
Also, You need to have this section (which I have modified for correctness):

```
# re = re/N This is not a part of the definition, remove it
# im = im/N Also not a part of the definition, remove it
h = (re, im)
X.insert(k, h)
```

inside of the first loop.

**Thirdly, Python has a built-in type to represent complex numbers.** So you want:

```
# There are other (more idiomatic?) ways to create a complex number, 
# but this probably looks natural to a Java dev
h = complex(re, im)
```

So, my modifications to make the DFT correct (by Wikipedia's definition) look like this:

```
import math
pi = math.pi

def dft(x):
    X=[]
    N = len(x)
    for k in range(0,N):
        re = 0
        im = 0
        for n in range(0,N):
            phi = (2*pi*k*n)/N

            re += (x[n]*math.cos(phi))
            im -= (x[n]*math.sin(phi))

        h = (re, im)
        X.insert(k, complex(re, im))

    return (X)
```

**Lastly, Python has some extremely powerful built-ins and 3rd party libraries, and it's wise to take advantage of them.** Although `numpy` is not *technically* a built-in, it's so widely used that it may as well be (and I think it actually ships with CPython on MacOS). `numpy` will be faster, more correct, and have better functionality/support/tooling than whatever you're going to throw together. The FFT has been a solved problem for a very long time now: no sense re-inventing the wheel! You can get `numpy` in your ecosystem with a simple `pip install numpy` in your shell (yes it's that easy, no Maven, no Gradle, no ANT, no nonsense!)

After the fixes described above, we get:

```
import numpy as np
def pretty_print_result(x):
    for item in x:
        print(item)
numpy_result = np.fft.fft([1,2,3,4,5,6])  # <-- This is the most "Pythonic" thing to do imo!
our_result = dft([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print('Numpys: ')
pretty_print_result(numpy_result)
print()
print('Ours: ')
pretty_print_result(our_result)
```

outputs:

```
Numpys:
(21+0j)
(-3+5.19615242271j)
(-3+1.73205080757j)
(-3+3.10862446895e-15j)
(-3-1.73205080757j)
(-3-5.19615242271j)

Ours:
(21+0j)
(-3.000000000000001+5.196152422706631j)
(-2.999999999999996+1.7320508075688759j)
(-3-1.286250527486674e-14j)
(-3.0000000000000084-1.7320508075688812j)
(-3.000000000000009-5.196152422706645j)
```

Which is the same result, minus some floating point shenanigans. Again, `numpy` will almost certainly be more accurate and faster than anything you're going to cobble together, and I can't recommend it enough for scientific computing.

**Quick speed comparison** (after loading this in IPython, and storing the modified `dft` function in a file called `test.py`):

```
In [1]: from test import dft

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: %timeit np.fft.fft([1,2,3,4,5])
The slowest run took 9.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit dft([1,2,3,4,5])
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.7 µs per loop
```

Hmm doesn't look too bad. It's roughly twice as fast. But remember, `numpy` is *algorithmically* faster (well...it's also running native code too), meaning that as the input grows, the speedup factor itself will increase as input grows:

```
In [5]: %timeit np.fft.fft(range(1000))
10000 loops, best of 3: 130 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit dft(range(1000))
1 loop, best of 3: 922 ms per loop
```

Now `numpy` is over 1000x faster, and it'll only get faster and faster over the naive version as input size grows.

HTH! And best of luck on your Python path!

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer. This little project is to combine my interest in coding and tutoring, as I hope to create a python version of: https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/617305c05001caffc8d0

Comment: I would like to keep the coding representative of the equation so students can follow along, but numpy is something I need to look more into. 
Yes, this is dft, that is my bad. In dft don't you divide by N to take the sum then average the contribution over N, for discrete fourier transform specifically?

Comment: @QQJJ If you're teaching students, then I'd recommend `numpy` _even more_. There's a difference between the DFT on the chalkboard and how we use it in software. No one would/should write a function to calculate a DFT, and that's worth knowing! I'd leave the pedantry to the chalkboard: software is about solving real problems. I'm working from this definition (which is pretty standard, although I have seen different definitions with a 1/N scale-factor for example, which is what I assume you're referring to): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition

Comment: @QQJJ If you use the `1/N` scale-factor you still need to make sure to move the `re = 0` and `im = 0` lines down in the first loop (need to set to 0 before every iteration) and the changes with the insert function as well. Also, when you invert, then you _don't_ have the `1/N` factor. The important thing here is that at a high level you need to have the invariant `fft(ifft(x)) == x`